# SharePoint Server 2013 questions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel, outlook

I'd like to know three things about MS SharePoint Server 2013.

1. As I'd like to simulate the version that enterprises are using, is the SharePoint Server a good version to simulate an Enterprise version?
2. For what concerns an Excel file sharing, is it possible to let numerous people edit the same file simultaneously (like in google docs)? Or what about the simultaneous consolidation of different files in one file?
3. Would Outlook 365 allow to do the same things?

Answer (score 0):

1) SharePoint Foundation Server and SharePoint Enterprise are the same on the Server side, it's the client licence which determines the version.  So not sure exactly what you are trying to simulate, but server-side it would be the same either way.

2) In theory Office Web Apps will allow collaborative editing, but Excel Online is much better at handling it.  I would personally discourage using Office Web Apps as Microsoft is pushing us all into SharePoint Online so I am not sure how much more work will be done to the non-Online versions.

3) Outlook 365?  Do you mean Office 365?  If so, you will find that "SharePoint Online" aka office 365 (depending on what Licence you sign up to) will do the client-side things that SharePoint 2013 does but you will not have access to server-side code such as DLLs written in C# etc.   You have to do everything with Javascript and the JSOM code.   That is the way Microsoft is pushing everything, so if you are trying to "learn" Sharepoint that would be the way to go, especially as it gives you transferable skills outside the SharePoint silo.

Comment: Thank you very much Robert! Yes, I meant Office 365. Actually I'm looking for a solution that can let many people co-editing the same file at the same moment. From your answer I understood that the right solution for that would be Office 365, is it right? However, with many people I mean more then 50.

Comment: Office 365 does do collaborative editing, but I don't think anyone has really nailed the simultaneous editing and seamless merging challenge yet.   On the bright side, it will be a cheap experiment.